# How to make a View blink after translation using Animation objects?

Tags: android, animation, android-view

I want to make 2 animations on one `View`, with the second one starting after the first one. The first one is translating and I use `TranslateAnimation` for that purpose and the second one is `AlphaAnimation` as I want the `View` to start blinking after translation. The problem is no matter what I'm doing these animations start simultaneously. As far as I'm concerned I should use `AnimationSet` object for this purpose but how to do this exactly? I even tried to use `setStartTime()` method to use some crazy value for the AlphaAnimation before putting it into `AnimationSet` but still the animations start immediately and simultaneously. So what should I do to prevent it from happening?

PS Here is what I tried to do and what didn't work:

```
    TextView cursor = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.cursor);
    Animation tAnim = new TranslateAnimation(-1000.f,200.0f,0.0f,0.0f);
    tAnim.setStartTime(0);
    tAnim.setDuration(3000);
    tAnim.setStartOffset(0);
    Animation bAnim = new AlphaAnimation(1.0f, 0.0f);
    bAnim.setStartTime(tAnim.getDuration());
    bAnim.setDuration(300);
    bAnim.setStartOffset(30);
    bAnim.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
    bAnim.setRepeatMode(Animation.REVERSE);
    AnimationSet s = new AnimationSet(false);
    s.addAnimation(tAnim);
    s.addAnimation(bAnim);
    cursor.startAnimation(s);
```

Comment: post the code from translating and alpha.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use this

```
   TextView cursor = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.cursor);
    Animation tAnim = new TranslateAnimation(-1000.f,200.0f,0.0f,0.0f);
    tAnim.setStartTime(0);
    tAnim.setDuration(3000);
    tAnim.setStartOffset(0);

    Animation bAnim = new AlphaAnimation(1.0f, 0.0f);
    bAnim.setStartTime(tAnim.getDuration());
    bAnim.setDuration(300);
    bAnim.setStartOffset(30);
    bAnim.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
    bAnim.setRepeatMode(Animation.REVERSE);

    tAnim.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {

        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation arg0) { }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation arg0) { }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation arg0) {
            cursor.startAnimation(bAnim);
        }
    });

    cursor.post(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            cursor.startAnimation(tAnim);
        }
    });
```

Make sure that **cursor** and **tAnim** are `instance/global` variable in your class, and also start the animation in the `post method` of the `TextView` to run it in **synchronize** with the textView

Answer (score 0):

Use animation listener. hope this works

```
Animation tAnim = new TranslateAnimation(-1000.f,200.0f,0.0f,0.0f);
tAnim.setStartTime(0);
tAnim.setDuration(3000);
tAnim.setStartOffset(0);
Animation bAnim = new AlphaAnimation(1.0f, 0.0f);
bAnim.setStartTime(tAnim.getDuration());
bAnim.setDuration(300);
bAnim.setStartOffset(30);
bAnim.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
bAnim.setRepeatMode(Animation.REVERSE);
AnimationListener AnimationListener = new AnimationListener(){

        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
            // TODO Animation start and end

        }
        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {

            //start the second animation here
            yourview.startAnimation(bAnim);
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }};
        tAnim.setAnimationListener(AnimationListener);
        yourview.startAnimation(tAnim);
        tAnim.hasEnded();
```

Comment: Reason for negative Grading..?

Comment: How to set TranslateAnimation as the animation that AnimationListener should listen to? I cannot see any methods for that in the class' documentation. (PS not the reason for grading (that wasn't me) just asking a question)